# Javascript stringifies JSON twice

Tags: javascript, json

In my app, I get some `JSON` data. If I try to save that data as global, pass it through `JSON.stringify()` and then through `JSON.parse()` it doesn't return as an object, but as a string. The `stringify` step returns a doubly encoded string:

[image]

What could make this happen? No one tampered the `JSON` object or the product object. Perhaps a special character in my object could cause this?

Comment: Does the `Object` inside the `products` array override the `toJSON` method?

Comment: Is your object already `stringified` when you call `stringify`? `console.log(typeof obj)`

Comment: @dr_debug there is no more relevant code... The object was pulled fresh from the Network tab and the JSON object is native...

Comment: @tymeJV That screenshot shows sequential commands with nothing happening in between. "Products" is a object until the end.

Comment: @IgorRaush Nah, this object is just data coming from an API...

Comment: Try using JSON.stringify(products.toJSON()) just for fun (not sure if it will do something)

Comment: Can you create a fiddle with the stringified object then, so the rest of us can play with it?

Comment: You do not need to stringify something which is already a JSON string. Just parse it.

Comment: @phenxd THAT'S IT! Post that as an answer and I'll accept it. I don't understand why, but the behaviour of `toJSON()` and `stringify()` is different...

Answer (score 1):

Per request from @ecc, this was moved from comment to answer.

Try using

```
JSON.stringify(products.toJSON())
```

I don't think this being necessary is normal behavior, though I'm having a hard time explaining why it is necessary in this case. Usually, the toJSON() gets called automatically in inside the `stringify` function.

EDIT : I just saw your answer, explains it!

Answer (score 0):

First of all why you need to stringify and then parse it for global context. As you can directly store the object to global.

Coming to your screenshot, the first time you are doing the stringify,at that point the variable was not an object. You can check the type. It seems like you are stringifying a string. May be not in console, but in code you have stringified the global variable and doing the same again in console. Check your code.

Comment: I assure you nothing happened and the variable passed to stringify is indeed the object printed in the first line. As for the use case, I need to stringify it to save it in local storage and then read it at some point in the future.

Comment: Yes of course the object needs to stringified before storing in local storage. But I am sure the first result of your stringify is when you stringify a string. coming to the special character point you mentioned I don't agree. But still you can try deleting the keys url and base64 as values before you stringify. Better we can resolve if you create a fiddle. Or can you post screenshot of the writing the exact value you get from the server to the console(no parse/ no stringify).

Answer (score 0):

I figured out who the culprit was: Prototype.
I found out through the console that Prototype was loaded in the faulty shop system. I solved it by removing stuff that was causing the problem:

```
if (window.Prototype) delete Array.prototype.toJSON;
```

I looked it up and the `stringify` method actually calls `toJSON` where available. Prototype was overriding it and screwing this up.